# Build FFTW for Apple M1 and the older intel devices

Tags: xcode, apple-m1, fftw, lipo

I built **FFTW** on my Apple m1 computer. When I run `lipo -info libfftw3.a` (which is located in `.libs/libfftw3.a`). It says it is of architecture **ARM64**.

In my Xcode I set the build target to 10.11, for backward compatibility.

Now when I add the FFTW library into my Xcode project, it complains:

> The linked library 'libfftw3.a' is missing one or more architectures
> required by this target: x86_64.

How can I solve this? Do I need to build the library in an Intel device and create a universal library with these two libraries together (using `lipo`) or what's the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it also with this line and it will build x86_64 & arm64 binary.

```
./configure CFLAGS="-arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=11.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to build a static library for both Intel and Apple silicon archictures, I need to build FFTW for both arch individually and then make an universal library. Here is how I do it.

1. Go to FFTW root folder
2. Build for Intel arch

   ./configure --prefix=/path/to/build/folder/lib-intel CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.11”
   make
   make install
3. Build for arm64

   ./configure --prefix=/path/to/build/folder/lib-arm64 CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.11”
   make
   make install
4. Make an universal build

   lipo -create path/to/build/folder/lib-intel/libfftw3.a path/to/build/folder/lib-intel/libfftw3.a -output libfftw3_universal.a
5. Include `libfftw3_universal.a` in the Xcode project